# How to Make 2D ArrayList of EditText in Android Studio using Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, arraylist, android-edittext

'''

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var button: Button? = null
    private var textList: ArrayList<ArrayList<EditText>> = arrayListOf(arrayListOf())
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.solve)

          textList[0][0]=findViewById<EditText>(R.id.ed1)
          textList[0][1]=(findViewById(R.id.ed2))
          textList[0][2]=(findViewById(R.id.ed3))
          textList[0][3]=(findViewById(R.id.ed4))
          textList[0][4]=(findViewById(R.id.ed5))
}
}
```

'''

I wanted to Store EditText in a 2D ArrayList but Above Method dosent work. I dont know why but it crashes the app when opened. So how should i do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
val list: ArrayList<Int> = arrayListOf()
list[0] = 123
```

means "replace the item at index 0 with `123`". But that's an empty list, there *is* no index 0. Imagine you used index 2 instead - if you *could* insert something there, what would be at indices 1 and 0? For something to be 3rd in a list, there needs to be a 2nd and 1st item, right?

You probably want an array instead:

```
private val rows = 5
private val columns = 5
private var textList: Array<Array<EditText>> = Array(rows) { arrayOfNulls(columns) }
```

That will create an array for each row, and it'll be filled with nulls, one for each column. Then you can assign them with `findViewById` (which can return null, which was another problem your `ArrayList` had - it could only hold non-null `EditText`s)

There are probably better ways to do what you're doing, but that's your basic issue here - can't update items in a list that don't exist. And an array makes more sense for a fixed structure you're going to be accessing by index